# python count duplicates in nexted list

Tags: python-3.x, mapreduce

I have a nested list and am trying to iterate through each list and save off the duplicates.
My list looks like this:

```py
conxn_out =  [
    ('6', [3, 4, 7, 13, 1, 3, 11, 1, 4, 11, 12, 1, 3, 4, 7]), 
    ('1', [7, 5, 9, 9, 11, 10, 2, 13, 3, 6, 11, 4, 7, 11, 12, 6, 4, 11, 12, 3, 6, 4, 7])
]
```

and I want my output to look like this:

```py
[
    ('6': {3:3, 4:3, 7:2, 1:3, 11:2}),
    ('1': {7:3, 9:2, 11:4, 3:2, 6:3, 4:3, 12:2})
]
```

So I need to find all duplicates in each list save off the number and the count.

I tried this:

```py
a = dict(Counter(conxn_out))
```

but I got `TypeError: Unhashable type: 'list'`. I guess that is because `Counter` won't work on nested lists.

So am I wondering what is the best way to do this. Would it be easier if I converted it back to a dictionary? I am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using `list` comprehension:

```
from collections import Counter

# [(i, Counter(l)) for i, l in conxn_out]
[(i, dict(Counter(l))) for i, l in conxn_out]
```

Output:

```
[('6', {3: 3, 4: 3, 7: 2, 13: 1, 1: 3, 11: 2, 12: 1}),
 ('1', {7: 3, 5: 1, 9: 2, 11: 4, 10: 1, 2: 1, 13: 1, 3: 2, 6: 3, 4: 3, 12: 2})]
```

Note that `Counter` doesn't have to be converted into `dict` explicitly since `Counter` is a subclass of `dict`:

```
issubclass(Counter, dict) == True
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and the info. I didn't know  Counter was a subclass of dict.